# Excel 2013 VBA Sort by rank

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

So here is the problem:

I need to interpolate values that are input to a template. Sounds easy, right? Well the problem is, those values aren't always in numerical order so it messes up my interpolation function. My interpolation function has an input of x values (in this case HP, this is the parameter that needs to be sorted numerically without messing up the data related to it), y values (the parameter you want to find at ?HP) and the x_value where you would like to find the y parameter. Some of the y parameters are equations so I couldn't think of a way to completely reorder the columns without messing up the data. I think there should be a way to reference the rank of the HP in the set, pick the related y value, and use those values to interpolate. That being said, I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I've been working on some code for quite a while. I've never actually used VBA before so it's been giving me a run for my money. The code I have thus far is as follows:

```
Function organize(ByVal x As Object)

' Declarations for finding Ranks
Dim Array_Size As Integer
Array_Size = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(x.cells) + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(x.cells)

Dim Ranks As Variant
ReDim Ranks(1 To Array_Size)
Dim j As Integer  'initiate counter

For j = 1 To Array_Size

    If x.cells(j).Value <> 0 Then

        Ranks(j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Rank_Eq(x.cells(i).Value, x.cells, 1) 'assign rank to i'th position in array

    End If

Next j

organize = Ranks()


End Function


Function lin_2xy(ByVal x1 As Single, ByVal y1 As Single, _
                 ByVal x2 As Single, ByVal y2 As Single, _
                 ByVal x_value As Single)

If x1 = x2 Then
   lin_2xy = [#N/A]
Else
   lin_2xy = y1 + (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (x_value - x1)
End If

End Function


Function Sort_Then_Interpolate(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object, ByVal x_value As Single)

'Declarations for interpolating
Dim i As Integer                ' counter.
Dim Current_x As Single       ' x value
Dim Next_x As Single          ' next higher x value
Dim Current_y As Single        ' y value
Dim Next_y As Single           ' next higher y value
Dim LFound As Boolean           ' = true if found.
Dim matrix() As Variant

matrix = organize(x.cells)

LFound = False

For i = 1 To UBound(matrix)

match_value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(i, matrix, 0)
next_match = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(i + 1, matrix, 0)

Current_x = x.cells(match_value).Value
Next_x = x.cells(next_match).Value
Current_y = y.cells(match_value).Value
Next_y = y.cells(next_match).Value

   If ((Current_x - x_value) * (Next_x - x_value) <= 0#) Then
      Sort_Then_Interpolate = lin_2xy(Current_x, Current_y, Next_x, Next_y, x_value)
      LFound = True

   End If
Next i

If (LFound = False) Then Sort_Then_Interpolate = [#N/A]

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Without delving too much into your code, based on your description, either a Collection or a Dictionary might help you. I'm also tempted to suggest using Classes, but those are very advanced if you're just starting out. In any case, can you post a link perhaps to a screenshot of your source data and the output you want? Someone, if not me, will edit the screenshot in from the link for you. This way, we can understand what you're attempting to do better.

Answer (score 0):

if that can help, you can sort a range in excel ( 'Home' Tab > 'Sort & Filter> ...)
i recorded a simple macro (sort A to Z in a given selected range):

```
Sub Macro3()
' This is an example code, from the record tool in excel, can be much upgraded...
' Sort A to Z
' change range to your needings

'
Range("A23:F27").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Epée batarde").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Epée batarde").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A23"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Epée batarde").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A23:F27")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

I think you use too much worksheetfunction, but really i didnt quite get your goal...
use Option explicit at the begin of your modules.

Functions return values, wich you might want to declare (easier to read , to us at least)

```
Function NameFunc (byval argument1 as Range, ...) as bolean 'or something
```

after LFound = True , maybe you can add exit for.

```
Array_Size = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(x.cells) + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(x.cells)
```

really writes like this:

```
'assuming x is a range or a worksheet, and not an object like you said, its like calling a chicken a bird)

'if x is a worksheet:
with x
    Array_Size = .cells( .rows.count,1).end(xlup).rows
end with

'if x is a range :
Array_Size = x.rows.count 'for counting rows
Array_Size = x.cells.count 'for counting number of cells
```

Maybe you can post a screen capture of your worksheet to help.
have a good evening